# For loop in Jinja2 splitting the chars in nested list, instead of returning whole of nested list

Tags: python, sql, flask, multidimensional-array, jinja2

My doubts list is [['a','b','This is a sentence']]
My HTML (Jinja) is

```
{% for x in doubts %}
{{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

My Flask is :-

```py
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1',database='wizlearn',user='root',password='pokemon2345')
    cursor = connection.cursor(buffered=True)
    login = session['login']
    admission_no = login[4]
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM doubts WHERE student = {0}'.format(admission_no))
    result = json.dumps(list(cursor.fetchall()))
    app.logger.debug(result)
    cursor.close()
    connection.close()
    return render_template('doubt_history.html', doubts=result)
```

x is giving `a,b,T,h,i,s,i,s,a,s,e,n,t,e,n,c,e` [Each char one iteration]

I expected `a,b,`This is a sentence. [Only one iteration]

How do I resolve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have dumped the output to json for some reason. Don't do that. Pass the value of `cursor.fetchall()` directly to the template.

Also, never ever pass user input - or any data - directly into an SQL query via string interpolation; this opens you to SQL injection attacks. Always use parameters:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM doubts WHERE student = %s', (admission_no))
```

(You haven't said what db you are using, if you are using sqlite you will need to use `?` instead of `%s` there.)